# Limit Phone Data Usage

Tags: mobile-data

This might be a replica, I have searched and not found a similar question.

I currently have the HTC One M8 and am planing on getting a 1GiB Data pack, knowing me who uses internet over the top I would like my internet to get cut at lets per say at the peak of 1GiB. So as soon as I reach it, it gets cut off fully.

1. I have tried the Android Data limiter and it always fails me.
2. I have not found any reliable applications (I will pay if worthy)
3. Location is Ontario and my provider is Fido

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I've just clicked on the [mobile-data tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-data?sort=frequent) you've used, and found a couple of questions helping you out. Have you e.g. seen [How does “Restrict background data” work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55831/16575) / [How can I disable unwanted data usage?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/69694/16575) / [How to prevent specific apps from using mobile data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75939/16575)

Comment: Check this, its very reliable and you can trust this too http://android.stackexchange.com/a/111252/108847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use AVG antivirus security which has an option to limit the used mobile data(not wifi data).
I fill information about data pack i.e amount and validity then give the option when to turn the mobile data off (as used in my case it is 90%)
then it ask if I want to further use the data..

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Post-ICS Android devices have in-built Data Limiter. Do this from `Settings` ~> `Data Usage` (can vary based on Android version).

Comment: If you read the question I state that this option NEVER WORKS.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone has an option to limit data built in. Go to Settings -> Data Usage and you can set Data Limits as well as a warning for when you have reached a certain amount. If you don't like this there are also third party apps like [Onavo Count](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid) that let you measure and limit your data usage

Comment: If you read the question I state that this option NEVER WORKS.

Comment: Well Onavo Data Count is an application I mentioned that you could try

Comment: Also by if it doesnt work you mean that it is allowing the data limit to be exceeded by a small margin resulting in overages, you can set the limit lower than your actual data limit incase your carrier accounts for data differently.